# Can $f(x) = \sin(nx)\sin(mx)$ $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$ be written as something in $A= \left\{\sum_{n=0}^k a_n \sin(n x): k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

$1.$ Can a product of sine functions $$f(x) = \sin(nx)\sin(mx)$$  $m,n \in \Bbb{N}$ be written as something in the set $$\left\{\sum_{n=0}^k a_n \sin(n x): k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
Asuming $a_n \in \Bbb{R} $?

I beleive not. I beleive it can be written, using trigonometric identities, as a sum of sines and cosines

$$\left\{\sum_{n=0}^k a_n \sin(n x) + \sum_{m=0}^j b_m \cos(m x): n, m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$$

$2.$ In the interval $[0, \pi]$ I claim that there don't exist injective functions in $$\left\{\sum_{n=0}^k a_n \sin(n x): k \in \mathbb{N}\right\},$$ because $\sin(nx)$ is not injective in that interval

True/False?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for a finite series, but f(x) would be periodic, and it is an even function, so it can be written as an infinite sum of cos(n*x) by it's Fourier representation. Apologies if this isn't of any help.